# How to reduce the div containers to put the content in the center?

Tags: html, css

There are two columns in the container,the left one is the png photo and the right is ul elements.
Both of them were set in the center of the div containers.

```css
div.whole{
 width:620px;
 overflow:auto;
 border:2px solid red;}

div.left,div.right{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height: 100%;
float:left;
width:300px;
height:200px;
}

div.box_left{    
width:120px;
height:120px;
}

div.box_right{
overflow:auto;
float:left;
}

li{ 
list-style:none;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
padding 0 0 0 0;
display:inline-block;   
border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
width:100px;}
```

```html
<div class="whole">
<div class="left">
   <div class="box_left">
   <img src="images/pic.png"  width="120"  height="120"/>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="right"> 
    <div class="box_right">       
    <ul>
    <li>x1</li><li>y1</li> 
    </ul>
    <ul>
    <li>x2</li><li>y2</li> 
    </ul>
    <ul>
    <li>x3</li><li>y3</li> 
    </ul><ul>
    <li>x4</li><li>y4</li> 
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]
There are five div containers here:div.whole,div.left,div.box_left,div.right,div.box_right.
It is a little burdensome for the simple work,5 div containers.
Can i reduce  two of them to get the same effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
div.whole {
 width:620px;
 display:table;
 border:2px solid red;
}

div.left, div.right {
  text-align:center;
  display: table-cell;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

ul{ padding:0; }

li {
  text-align:left;
  list-style:none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding 0 0 0 0;
  display:inline-block;   
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
  width:100px;
}
```

And html:

```
<div class="whole">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="images/pic.png" width="120" height="120"/>
  </div>
  <div class="right">       
    <ul>
      <li>x1</li><li>y1</li> 
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>x2</li><li>y2</li> 
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>x3</li><li>y3</li> 
    </ul><ul>
      <li>x4</li><li>y4</li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example: https://jsbin.com/saqecaseji/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

use text align center  for horizontal alignment i.e  css `text-align:center`  and

```
line-height:'some pixel' for vertical center
```